# App needs accurate localization - huge battery drain

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, battery

one of our programmers developed an app that needs some geotagging capabilities:

- the app is not a mapping one and does not need a constant knowledge of current user position
- **the app needs to know the current position ONLY when the user uses a particular geotag feature**, but it has to be as accurate as possible (a pretty common one use case anyway)

The problem is that the devices shows a huge battery drain that completely depletes them in 2 hours.

The code prodeced shows a Service that every 10 seconds check for the current location, I guess maybe this is the problem since it doesn't do an *ad hoc* check:

```
public class BatchService extends Service {

    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000;  /* 10 secs */
    private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 2000; /* 2 sec */
    public String latitudine;
    public String longitudine;
    public int count;

    PowerManager pm;
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl;

    private static BatchService istanza;

    public static BatchService getInstance()
    {
        if (istanza == null)
        {
            istanza = new BatchService();
        }

        return istanza;
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable periodicUpdate = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(periodicUpdate, 10000);
            count = 0;
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    };

    private boolean isRunning  = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");

        isRunning = true;

        pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "GpsTrackerWakelock");
        wl.acquire();
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {

        // Create the location request to start receiving updates
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);


        // Create LocationSettingsRequest object using location request
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        LocationSettingsRequest locationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

        // Check whether location settings are satisfied
        // https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient
        SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
        settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequest);

        // new Google API SDK v11 uses getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
      getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                        if(count==0){
                            count++;
                            onLocationChanged(locationResult.getLastLocation());
                        }




                    }
                },
                null);

  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location!=null){
            // New location has now been determined
                if(location.getAccuracy()<=50){
                    getInstance().latitudine = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
                    getInstance().longitudine = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
                }else{
                    getInstance().latitudine = null;
                    getInstance().longitudine = null;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

What can we investigate in order to resolve our issues and to better handle this kind of cases?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for; you already know you should not be requesting location constantly when you don't need it. What else are you looking for?

Comment: Essentially a confirmation of that statement and a more correct way to go, because the asyncronous nature of the call for the location update makes it more difficult to retrieve it when wee need it if we make an ad hoc call. So they opted for this workaround.

Comment: test test timezone